# Scenario for exhausted close votes without using review quota

Tags: discussion, bug, review, vote-to-close

Consider the following scenario

```
Daily CV limit : 50
Daily CV limit through review : 40
```

I cast 15 CVs manually and then proceed to finish my daily CV quota from the review page. I would expect that the CV section on the review page should be closed for me, asking me to continue reviewing after a certain amount of time.

However, what actually happens, is that I can still click the CV section, with 0 votes remaining. Please see the screenshot below.

[image: bugged close votes]

In the case where I've hit the daily CV limit, that is, if I've cast 50 CVs without going to the review tab, or if I've cast less than 0 CVs from the review tab but have still hit the daily limit, I should not be able to go to the CV section from the review tab.

Comment: You can still skip questions until you find some that needs to stay open.